# input box value will save to mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

var i=0,j=0;

var t1= [];

function add(){

    i++;

    var parent = document.forms[0];

    var div = document.createElement('div');

    var input = document.createElement('input');

    input.type='text';

    input.name='text'+i;

    input.value = "text"+i;

    input.size = 10;

    t1.push(input);

    div.appendChild(input);

    var removeButton = document.createElement("button");

    removeButton.innerHTML = "Remove";

    removeButton.onclick = function(e) {

        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
        return(false);

    };

    div.appendChild(removeButton);

    var mybr=document.createElement("br");

    div.appendChild(mybr);

    parent.appendChild(div);

}
</SCRIPT>

<button onclick="add()">+</button>

<form action='generate.php' method='get'>

<input type='submit' name='button' value='save'>

</form>
```

This is a running code... I wonder what code can put the value of each textbox to a mysql database
mybe by the use of this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `sampledb` SET  `text1` =  'anyvaluethatuserinputs' && `text2` =  'anyvaluethatuserinputs' && `text3` =  'anyvaluethatuserinputs'";
```

but how...

Comment: the missing code below is <html>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>

<form action='generate.php' method='get'>

<input type='submit' name='button' value='save'>

</form>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your generate.php. You will be able to get the value of the textboxs along with the id of the textbox in a string.

```
<?php

$sql = "UPDATE `sampledb` SET  ";


if(isset ($_GET))
{

    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) 
        $sql .= "$key = '$value'  , ";

}

$sql= substr_replace ($sql , '', strlen($sql) -2 , 1);
echo $sql;

    //here establish the connection and pass the $sql as the query

?>
```

Comment: do u know how to remove the numbers 1,2 and 3 and so on.... in the, text1,text2 and text3.. it should be text only, inorder to save in my database the output was: text1 = 'anyvalue' , text2 = 'anyvalue' , text3 = 'anyvalue'......  ty u help me a lot

Comment: which 'textN' [where n=0,1,2,3...] you are talking about ? In the key part or in the value part ?
If you are talking about the value part then try putting values in the textbox , it will change . And if you are talking about the key part , you have to change the name of the textboxs.

Comment: sorry sir. im confuse to update, i need is insert T_T sorry i apologize "
INSERT INTO  `test`.`new` (`id` ,`text` ,`age` ,`bday`)VALUES (NULL ,  'anyvalue1',  '',  '',  ''), (NULL ,  'anyvalue2',  '',  '',  ''), (NULL ,  'anyvalue3',  '',  '',  '');" like this sorry again

Comment: what is the column name of your database? Those should be predefined , right?

Comment: <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con){ echo mysql_error(); }
mysql_select_db("test");


$sql = "INSERT INTO  `test`.`new` (
`id` ,
`keynum` ,
`name` ,
`datereg` ,
`amount`
)
VALUES  ";


if(isset ($_GET))
{

    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) 
        $sql .= "(NULL ,  '$value',  '',  '',  '')";

}

$sql= substr_replace ($sql , '', strlen($sql) -2 , 1);
echo $sql;

$sql1 = "$sql";
$result = mysql_query($sql1);

?>

Comment: At first my suggestion would be to edit your question.
And after that , please be precise about what you want and give a clear description about your skill also. Otherwise it will be kind of hard to help you.

Make sure you understand how database and php works also. Your code sample indicates that you lack some basic skills.

Comment: SIr  MD. Sahib Bin Mahboob thank you i already solve my problem thx to ur example, it gave me a lots of idea, thx again

Comment: @Robert welcome. The most important thing is you got your solution :)